# Why there is no option to forward/backward next/back while in PiP mode?

Tags: google-chrome

I know there is picture in picture mode on google chrome. I really enjoy it when learning on Udemy and following along.

Or watching something on Youtube and doing something else parallely.

One thing bothers me most, I have to go back to browser again and do previous/next rewind/forward or to play next video.

These options are not there in picture in picture mode. Only play/pause works.

Even if It can show seekbar on hover, that will also be very helpful.

How can I enable these options?

*Update:
Just tried on Firefox. Firefox supports video shortcuts to provide controls over playback.*

Comment: Thank you for the update. I switched to FF just for this ;)

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but since I just had to do this myself, here's a straightforward solution. [This](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wipeyy-controllable-pictu/mgbnhohohiggdomiccdpkhaponabbfbc) chrome extension allows you to set global shortcuts to pause, play, rewind and fast-forward in PiP mode.

If it doesn't work immediately, just refresh the page.

Comment: At least it's something, thanks.